# SublimeText autocomplete dictionary

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext

I have just installed SublimeText for my Markdown editing. Problem is regarding the autocomplete [plug-in](https://github.com/Zinggi/DictionaryAutoComplete). I don't know why  the autocomplete is showing up just Italian words. I saw in the [Readme](https://github.com/Zinggi/DictionaryAutoComplete/blob/master/README.md) that the dictionary by default is set to

```
"dictionary": "Packages/Language - English/en_US.dic"
```

So I changed my user preferences setting the English dictionary but when I save it I get this error message:

```
Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in Packages/User/DictionaryAutoComplete.sublime-settings:1:13
```

Anyway is there an option in SublimeText like *check spelling while typing* ?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F6</kbd> by default enables spell checking. You may configure this yourself, this is an excerpt from the default settings on linux:

```
{ "keys": ["f6"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args": {"setting": "spell_check"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f6"], "command": "next_misspelling" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f6"], "command": "prev_misspelling" },
```

For an explanation about the error you're having update your question with the contents of your settings file `Packages/User/DictionaryAutoComplete.sublime-settings`